# If $I=\frac{kr}{(r^2+a^2)^{3/2}}$, where K and a are constants, find $\frac{dt}{dr}$

Tags: derivatives

I just have one problem in this. How do we find $\frac{dt}{dr}$ when there is no t given. I think I can solve the rest if am able to understand this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is $t$ in your formula?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That's what he has mentioned, *when there is no t given*

Comment: Only makes sense if $r = r(t)$. If so then you should compute $\frac{dr}{dt} = \dot{r}$ and then compute $1/\dot{r}$ - Even then you have $I(r)$ which needs to be handled.

Comment: @Chinny84 I don’t follow. Please simplify it

Comment: It is almost certainly a typo. Likely they want you to find $$\frac {dI}{dr}$$.

Comment: Maybe, but I still needed to get that cleared out